# Can I change the controls for Sid Meier's Pirates?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

I recently got this game because I felt like playing it again but it's been such a long time and I now don't feel comfortable using the numpad and arrow keys to control my ship. However, there is no way to change the key mapping in the options. Is there any way to change the controls because at this point the control scheme makes it unplayable?